# Do parameter values get passed to secomd minimizer call in lmfit

Tags: python, lmfit

I'm using lmfit to fit some data to a two reaction system in order to estimate the rate constants. My data are the changes in concentration of x1, x2, and x3 species in x1 -> x2 -> x3

In other tools, I generally use a global optimizer followed by a local optimizer so I can more easily get access to the Hessian etc. In lmfit I thought I could do something like:

```
minimizer = lmfit.Minimizer(self._residuals, params)
result = minimizer.minimize(method='differential_evolution')
result = minimizer.minimize(method='leastsqr')
```

I assumed that the parameters fitted by the differential evolution would remain in the minimized object and get picked up automatically by the second minimize function call.

However, I am not sure because I colleague of mine suggested otherwise. If anyone knows the lmfit package better, does the second minimize pick up the parameters where the first minimize left off?

Update 1: I added the Minimize call to ensure you that only one Minnizmize object is created. My current tests appear to indicate that the parameter values do get passed from one minimize call to another (which is what I'd expect).

Update 2: Further experiments indicate if the system is non-identifiable, then there is a difference, meaning that the first call to minimize doesn't appear to pass on its fitted parameters to the second minimize call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the fitted parameters from the first method will not be used in the second minimization with the code you provided.

If you don't specify anything for `minimizer.minimize()` it will start from the `params` you supplied to initialize the `Minimizer` class. The code below should do what you want:

```
minimizer = lmfit.Minimizer(self._residuals, params)
result_de = minimizer.minimize(method='differential_evolution')
result = minimizer.minimize(params=result_de.params, method='leastsqr')
```

(I am assuming here that `self._residuals` is your fitting function, i.e., what you want to be minimized). Please check the documentation [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html).